# Finding a process's filename from its PID?

Tags: command-line, process

I'm trying to figure out what program keeps [killing the network indicator](https://askubuntu.com/questions/218882/networking-icon-keeps-disappearing):

```
$ nm-applet
** Message: applet now removed from the notification area
** Message: PID 31340 (we are 28924) sent signal 15, shutting down...
```

The PIDs change every time. Is there a way to use that PID to find the name of the process that's stopping it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If PID 31340, a simple `ps uww 31340` will tell you. `ls -l /proc/31340` will show you more information, for example `/proc/31340/exe` is a symbolic link to the program executable in case the name wasn't enough.

If PID 31340 isn't running anymore, it's too late unless you've installed some kind of logging software.

The simplest logging software for this job is [acct](http://packages.ubuntu.com/aptacct) [image: Install acct]. Just install the package and it will start logging the name of all processes. The next time you want to know about some past PID, run

```
sudo dump-acct /var/log/account/pacct | grep 31340
```

For a more precise match of the last process that had this PID, you can use this incantation:

```
sudo dump-acct /var/log/account/pacct | awk -F '|' '$10 ~ /^ *31340 / {print; quit}'
```